# I can't figure out how to make my JS loop only continue if one of the callbacks is true

Tags: javascript, for-loop, break, continue

I am trying to make a `for` loop continue **only** if one of two callbacks (`resolve` or `reject`) is `true` inside of `tds.init` function. I cannot figure it out at all. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

My code is below:

```
for (var i = 0; i < threeDSCards.length; i++) {
  $("input[name='cc_number']").focus();
  $("input[name='cc_number']").val(threeDSCards[i]["cardnumber"]);

  $("select[name='expmonth']").focus();

  if (threeDSCards[i]["expMonth"] < 10) {
    var month = '0';
    month += threeDSCards[i]["expMonth"];
  } else {
    var month = threeDSCards[i]["expMonth"];
  }

  $("select[name='expmonth']").val(month);

  $("select[name='expyear']").focus();
  $("select[name='expyear']").val(threeDSCards[i]["expYear"]);

  $("input[name='cc_cvv']").focus();

  var resolve = function (response) {
    console.log("Manual Response Received", response);
  }

  var reject = function (error) {
    console.log("Error Received!", error);
    console.log(error);
    console.log(error != "Error: Cardholder not participating" &&
        error != "Error: Something went wrong, Please Contact Support" ?
          "card is good" : "card is bad");
  }

  var rebillResolve = function (response) {
    console.log("Rebill Response Received", response);
  }

  var rebillReject = function (error) {
    console.log("Rebill Error Received", error);
  }

  var tds = new ThreeDS("order", "https://example.com/test/form/checkout.php", { verbose: true });
  tds.init(resolve, reject, rebillResolve, rebillReject);
}
```

Good documentation for this software can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/3dsintegrator/threeds-php-sdk/src

Comment: What do you mean by "*one of two callbacks is true*"? A callback *function* never is the boolean value `true`.

Comment: What is `ThreeDS` and how does it use these callbacks? If it's asynchronous, you likely cannot use a `for` loop anyway.

Comment: It's a credit card verification system. I don't think it's asynchronous. What would I do instead of a for loop?

Comment: What I mean by true is when the callback is completed.

Comment: If it's synchronous, then the callback will be completed by the time that `tds.init(…)` returns. But since you're having problems with this code, it's likely to be asynchronous.

Comment: If it's asynchronous what would I use instead of a for loop?

Comment: You'd go for a recursive approach. Have the function do one step at one index, then in the callback call the function again for the next index until you've reached the end of the array.

Comment: If you could point us to some documentation for `ThreeDS` and its `init` method we would more likely be able to help you.

Comment: I added a good and concise source of documentation to the question. The link I provided is here: https://bitbucket.org/3dsintegrator/threeds-php-sdk/src